# Log is truncated after 30 seconds

Tags: grafana-loki

I have been playing around Loki and done some experiments. But I just find that when there was new log/text added to log file, I could see it at first (in Grafana Explorer) but it was gone if I ran the same query again after around 30 seconds. Did I accidentally break something during experiments?

I've also tried to use this config (https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/examples/#complete-local-config) and changed *chunk_retain_period* to 90s but it was still gone after around 30 seconds.

I guess the Promtail config should have nothing to do with this issue, right? Could you please let me know what I may do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How many log lines are returned by your query?

Comment: Only one or two - this is only for testing.